# Web Push Notification with Encrypted Payload in Python

Tags: django, python-2.7, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can someone please explain how to send notification with Payload for Chrome using Python/Django

I am doing so-

```
    fcm_url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    encoded = WebPusher(subscription_info).encode(json.dumps(data))

    crypto_key = "dh=" + encoded["crypto_key"]
    salt = "salt=" + encoded['salt']

    headers = {'Authorization': 'key=' + gcm_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json', }
    headers.update({'crypto-key': crypto_key, 'content-encoding': 'aesgcm', 'encryption': salt})    

    fcm_data = {"raw_data":base64.b64encode(encoded.get('body')), "registration_ids": ['eYXdX1V94XY:APA91bHPQdnlQiVwe5HmWnRQrtpOnHzAJ4kEHNgB8GrEZ_YxSgtwz-0gvcpUFBAb3_eVXOVcJAjvVotGfKl9jLGM_X6nZb76YzFBZazMu1auIDAXhXjUgFDHm7E2ffRpBD70rpD1qC1r']}

    resp = requests.post(fcm_url,data=json.dumps(fcm_data),headers=headers)
```

Output:-

```
{"multicast_id":6483153199368608385,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1481362362576359%958b01adf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

but the notification doesn't contain the above specified Data.

Comment: I think this question is similar to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729729/chrome-web-push-notification-with-encrypted-payload-in-python).

Comment: Yes,This is same but not working for me and i could not comment for this thread so...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are mixing the Web Push Protocol and the Firebase Cloud Messaging API.

Are you trying to send a request to a normal open web PushSubscription, or are you trying to send to a Firebase token?

If you are using the Firebase Messaging SDK for web, then you don't need to encrypt the payload (It's one of the main reasons for using the firebase messaging SDK).

If you are using just the normal open web API's and not touching the Firebase Messaging SDK, I'd check out: https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush